# How do I pass variable to controller

Tags: symfony

I create my own bundle. There is a class in this bundle.

In this class I have a variable `$Url`. I would like to use this variable in my controller in another bundle. How do I pass a variable to a controller in a different bundle?

Comment: Is $url a config-type/application variable? Would you expect to set the variable in your applications config.yml?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best option is to create a Controller as a Service. You can read about that in [a blog article by Richard Miller](http://richardmiller.co.uk/2011/04/15/symfony2-controller-as-service/).

After you have done that, you can create a service parameter with the value of `$Url`:

```
# app/config/config.yml
parameters:
    my_first_bundle.url: Some value

services:
    # request and response services
    my.response: 
        class: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
    my.request: 
        class: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request

    # controller services
    my_second_bundle.mycontroller: 
        class: Acme\MySecondBundle\Controller\MyController
        arguments: [ %my.response%, %my.request%, %my_first_bundle.url% ]
```

Comment: in my bundle (where it is the variable $ url) I do not use any Controller

Comment: @PawełBrzoski that is right, I mean the Controller in the other bundle (which I called `my_second_bundle` in the code).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to turn that class into a service and set the $url value with dependency injection.. Or you may néed to persist the $url if you plan to modify $url in one controller and access it again in another controller later on. Either way, you'll need to turn that class file into a service.